# Is the property of being a dg generator open?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a dg category (over some base) with all colimits. We say that $X\in \mathcal{C}$ is a generator if $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{End}_\mathcal{C}X$-modules (via the Yoneda functor). My question: are there some "niceness" conditions we can impose on the pair $(\mathcal{C}, X)$ which guarantee that all deformations of $X$ (i.e. all fibers of a suitably perfect sheaf of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ over a curve with special fiber $X$, say) are still generators?

Comment: Rigidity is sufficient.

Comment: You mean non-existence of nontrivial deformations? Thanks :)

Comment: Could you explain or give a reference for what do you mean by a sheaf of objects of $\mathcal C$ here?

Comment: I am open to interpretation. But a simple working definition on an affine variety $\text{Spec}(R)$ would be a compact object in the category of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ with $R$-action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me give an example (which you are probably aware of) that shows how a generator may become a non-generator after a deformation.

Let $\mathcal C$ be the derived category of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $X = \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)[1]$. This is clearly a generator. On the other hand, we can deform the sum to an extension
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_P \to 0,
$$
where $P \in \mathbb{P}^1$ is a point, and the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_P$ is definitely not a generator.

I think a similar trick can be used in a much more general situation, so I do not believe there is a reasonable condition (besides the rigidity of $X$) ensuring that the property "being a generator" is open.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great example that I should have thought of before posting. I suppose it shows that the dga $\text{End}^*_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}_P)$ is a deformation of $\text{End}^*_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)[1]),$ but they are not deformations in the opposite order (which is why I was curious about this)